# Why does conversion from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:9451 only leads to swapped coordinates?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geopandas, epsg, united-kingdom

```
import shapely.wkt
import geopandas as gpd
```

---

I have a shapely polygon and a GeoSeries:

```
p = shapely.wkt.loads('POLYGON((-3 50,-3 51,-2 51,-2 50,-3 50))')
s = gpd.GeoSeries(p,crs=4326)
```

`print(s)` returns:

```
0    POLYGON ((-3.00000 50.00000, -3.00000 51.00000...
dtype: geometry
```

as expected. As expected, `print(s.to_crs(25833))` returns something different:

```
0    POLYGON ((-786007.516 5695743.458, -758424.471...
dtype: geometry
```

so does `s.to_crs(3006)`:

```
0    POLYGON ((-786007.516 5695743.458, -758424.471...
dtype: geometry
```

However, the output of `print(s.to_crs(9451))` is nearly the same as that of `print(s)`, except the coordinates are swapped:

```
0    POLYGON ((50.00000 -3.00000, 51.00000 -3.00000...
dtype: geometry
```

This is surprising, because EPSG:9451 has meters as units, according to https://epsg.io/9451.

What am I missing here? Does EPSG:9451 not use metres as units, or did the conversion fail?

Context: I have some Polygons covering the UK, in `EPSG:4326`. I need to simplify these polygons in a coordinate system where the unit is metres. That is why the need for conversion. It seems [EPSG:9451](https://epsg.io/9451) have metres as units, so seems like a good target, except it does not work as expected, illustrated above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EPSG 9451 is a *Vertical* coordinate system only. If you have points with heights, you'd use it to specify the height system:

```
Coordinate system: Vertical CS. Axis: height (H). Orientation: up. UoM: m.
```

The standard metric grid system for Great Britain is https://epsg.io/27700 which is a Cartesian 2D coordinate system:

```
 Coordinate system: Cartesian 2D CS. Axes: easting, northing (E,N). Orientations: east, north. UoM: m.
```

This doesn't explain why the coordinates are flipped, but I suspect somewhere PROJ is assuming (lat,long) is (X,Y) and the output is then (X,Y,Z).